# DBT Cloud: Python Model Deployment Issue

Tags: python, dbt

I am running a python model and it works fine on my `dbt core` enviroment but when I deploy it to `dbt cloud` it throws the follwing error:

```
09:22:19 78 of 83 START python table model bi_core.bt_f_mail_data__demo ................. [RUN]
E0831 09:22:20.512051123     400 hpack_parser.cc:992]                  Error parsing 'content-type' metadata: invalid value
09:22:20  Unhandled error while executing target/run/dbt_bi_officeservice/models/bi_core/sats/fullrefresh/bt_f_mail_data__demo.py
None Stream removed
09:22:20 78 of 83 ERROR creating python table model bi_core.bt_f_mail_data__demo ........ [ERROR in 0.56s]
```

my Python model:

```
def model(dbt, session):
   dbt.config(
              materialized = "table",
              tags= ["python"],
              submission_method="serverless",
              #packages = ["numpy==1.23.1", "scikit-learn"]
             )
   sql_model = dbt.ref('bt_f_mail_data')
   df = sql_model.to_pandas_on_spark()
   return df
```

Can someone pls help me here, if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my problem. It was `dataproc_region` that was the wrong one. Now it works on my dbt core env. and the deployment on dbt cloud also works fine.